# Elastic Beanstalk unable to install packages

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am getting this error and totally unable to see where the problem is.

The below is the code present in `.ebextensions/mysite-env.config`

```
packages:
  yum:
    python-devel: []
    postgresql-devel: []

container_commands: 
  01_syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_createadmin: 
    command: "scripts/createadmin.py"
    leader_only: true

option_settings: 
  - option_name: WSGIPath
    namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python"
    value: "mysite/wsgi.py"
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: "mysite.settings"
```

After several hit-and-try methods, I figured out few things

1. The above config file seems to run after `requirements.txt` present in root
2. Unable to install those packages (mentioned above) but I could get installed by getting into `ssh` of the EC2 instance (weird)

The issue with `[1]` is that, for `psycopg2` to install, I need the above mentioned packages. So, how do I install them first?

When I run these settings, I am getting the below error:

```
[2014-11-19T09:45:19.819Z] INFO  [6703]  - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Activity execution failed, because: command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Yum does not have postgresql-devel available for installation (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Then, I used the below settings

packages:
  yum:
    python-devel: []
  apt:
    postgresql-devel: []

Then I am getting the below error:

```
[2014-11-19T09:47:54.271Z] ERROR [6789]  : Command execution failed: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: [Errno 2] No such file or directory (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError)
    at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.0/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:189:in `rescue in exec'
    ...
caused by: command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: [Errno 2] No such file or directory (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

When I could install those packages directly from `ssh`, whats the problem with automation? What's wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 6):

Use postgresql93-devel in the yum statement as they have updated the package names

```
packages:
  yum:
    python26-devel: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
```

Comment: As of Dec 2015, having `python-devel` as a package dependency gives `Yum does not have python-devel available for installation` in Beanstalk.

Comment: @jmq, do you know how to install python-devel with yum? I'm trying to install on AWS but am getting "Yum does not have python-devel available for installation".

Comment: @tmthyjames I don't. My attempt at installing it was at the recommendation of some various blog posts I'd found relating to some other dependencies my project has, but I found that I didn't need it after all for my purposes. One thing to consider though is investigating the `--enablerepo=epel` option when writing custom commands. Ref [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/). Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: @jmq try `python26-devel`

Answer (score 2):

I could not find another way than installing these packages by hand.

```
packages:
  yum:
    ...

commands:
  01_python_devel_install:
    command: 'yum install -y python34-devel'

  02_postgresql_install:
    command: 'yum install -y postgresql94 postgresql94-devel'
```

I am starting with elastic beanstalk and this does not give me a good first impression.

Answer (score 2):

Heres the correct way according to AWS.

Python 3

```
packages:
  yum:
    python34-devel: []
    postgresql94-devel: []
```

Python 2.7

```
packages:
  yum:
    python27-devel: []
    postgresql94-devel: []
```

[Reference](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=233268)